# Yii2 kartik datetime picker widget doesn´t function?

Tags: yii2, datetimepicker

I wanted put yii2 kartik datetimepicker into a reservation room form, but datepicker doesn´t function.
Im sure , i have `use kartik/datetime/DateTimePicker;` at the top of code.

This is my code for reservation form. Its not complete, but i want test posting date.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Booked room from </label>
    <?php
    echo DateTimePicker::widget([
                'name' => 'date_in_modal_1',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Date and time...'],
                'pluginOptions' => ['autoclose' => true]
    ]);

    ?>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label> Booked room to </label>
<?php
echo DateTimePicker::widget([
            'name' => 'date_in_modal_2',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Date and time...'],
            'pluginOptions' => ['autoclose' => true]
]);

?>
</div>

  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

I using the same code in index view and this work. The inputs shows, but if i click, the form with date pick and time pick doesn´t show. Can someone help me with this problem?
Thanks u all.

Comment: debug your code for error in browser using firebug , etc. or so whole form.

Comment: ah, there is a problem `<pre>PHP Notice &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Undefined index: room_number_of_people&#039; 

in C:\wamp\www\raporty\frontend\modules\worker\controllers\RoomController.php:77`

Comment: and there is my controller : `public function actionUpdateroomrow(){
      $model = Rooms::findOne($_POST['id']);
      $model -> room_number_of_people = $_POST['room_number_of_people'];
      $model->update();
 } idk what i going wrong, in database is this set right`

Comment: `$model -> room_number_of_people = $_POST['room_number_of_people'];` this is the line 77 :/

Comment: seems like your $_post doesn't contain any data.

Comment: its interesting, cuz in tables i have datas  -.- and in other controllers i have similar code and it work perfectly

Comment: go through it carefully and find what you are missing?

Comment: i tried use this: ` if ( isset($_POST['room_number_of_people'] ))
      $model -> room_number_of_people = $_POST['room_number_of_people']; ` yes the form is now in new blank ..but there is not field for edit number of people -.-